# using siglongjmp effectively

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a shell like program which runs in a loop; it accepts few commands and do the required functionality. 
Program exits only when "getout" command is called.

Let us suppose if a segmentation fault signal is occured, I just handle cleanup my program and instead of exiting the program I just wanted to stay inside. 
I could acheive this using siglongjmp() call.

My problem: When I run my shell program again in my recover function, and when any segmentation fault is occurred now, my signal is not caught for cleanup and program exits with segmentation fault.

Please suggest a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
sigjmp_buf mark;

void myhandler(int signo)
{
my_action();
siglongjmp(mark,-1);
}

recover()
{
my_program_loop();
}

my_program_loop()
{
/* accept some commands and do some functionality*/
/*some part of the code may cause segfault*/
}


main()
{
     if (sigsetjmp(mark,0) != 0)
    {
        printf("siglongjmp() is called\n");
        recover();
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sigaction myhandle;
    myhandle.sa_handler = myhandler;
    sigemptyset(&myhandle.sa_mask);
    myhandle.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SEGSEGV, &myhandle, NULL);

    my_program_loop();

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Avoid getting `SIGSEGV` in the first place. Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -g` and debug it with `gdb`. Perhaps use `valgrind` to chase memory bugs.

Comment: Lol, got the solution. In the matter of hurry, I did not save the current signal mask.

while using sigsetjmp(sigjmp_buf env, int savemask), if the value of the savemask argument is not 0, sigsetjmp() will also save the current signal mask of the calling thread as part of the calling environment.

in the above code, in main(), if sigsetjmp(mark,0) should be modified to sigsetjmp(mark,1) and it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

You should have a problem with your « my_program_loop », I can catch very well the signal with this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

sigjmp_buf mark;

void myhandler(int signo) {
    printf("Sig caught\n");
    siglongjmp(mark, -1);
}

void my_program_loop(void) {
    char *p = NULL;
    *p = 5;
}

void recover(void) {
    my_program_loop();
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction myhandle;

    if (sigsetjmp(mark, 0) == -1) {
        recover();
        exit(1);
    }

    myhandle.sa_handler = myhandler;
    sigemptyset(&myhandle.sa_mask);
    myhandle.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &myhandle, NULL);

    my_program_loop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may I know if you could catch it everytime?

Comment: It seems to me you can only catch it ONCE